# Unity camera not moving

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm trying to get started with Google Tango for Unity by following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-prefab-motion-tracking

But when I build and run my project, the gyroscope doesn't seem to work and the camera doesn't respond.

I'm using Unity 4.6.7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see the minimum version of Unity that's required, if any. You could always try the latest Unity and see if that fixes it? If necessary, you could try the latest Unity and project tango on another computer to see if it's the issue before upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

All of the samples have worked for me without issue in unity 5.1.3f1 personal.

you could try connecting adb logcat and observe for errors during execution.

find ADB.exe in the android SDK directory

from a command prompt run it with the parameters 'adb.exe logcat -c' to clear the logfile, then again without the -c and watch for errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm using the latest version at the moment, 5.2, and it doesn't work.

I have observed the console in adb but it didn't show me any problems at all.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that under build Player settings, when I have multithreaded rendering enabled the augmented reality samples camera display stops working.  it still produces acurate depth samples but it doesn't actually show the camera.  is it only in the samples you're trying to use that the camera doesn't work or does the camera never work at all?

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, the gyroscope on some Android devices is disabled by default, assuming the device has one. So you might need to enable it when the app starts up to make sure it is being used, by using Input.gyro.enabled = true;

It also might be that the app is for whatever reason not asking for permissions, which is then resulting in the app being automatically denied access to the gyroscope and camera by the device.

There might also be some other logic that is interfering or altering the gyro data in some way. It's very unlikely, but possible, so it might be worth looking into if all other suggestions fail.

Hope you find a solution soon.